# Security headers present in browser, but scanner claims they are missing

Tags: .net, https, http-headers

I am developing a website where I have added the `Strict-Transport-Security` and `Content-Security-Policy` headers on the server. The server is a .NET API and the headers are added in `Startup.cs` like this (simplified code):

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHsts(options =>
        {
            options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
            options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
        });
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseForwardedHeaders();
        
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self';");
            await next();
        });

        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseRateLimiter();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.CustomMapHealthChecks();

            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

Now when accessing the website and checking the network tab I can see both headers there

[image]

However when I scan the website using securityheaders.com, it claims that both headers are missing.

[image]

So basically my question is what is going on here? Is my app configured correctly and securityheaders.com is wrong, or is there something else going on behind the scenes that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Check the webserver access log which URLs are executed by that scanner web page and perform the requests on your own.